# Was Emil Blonksy a failure as a super-soldier?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, captain-america, the-incredible-hulk, marvel, the-incredible-hulk-2008

In The Incredible Hulk, Emil Blonksy receives a serum based on that from Project: REBIRTH that is intended to make him a stronger, faster soldier. Based on the events at the University confrontation with The Hulk, this was a success.

However as Erskine states in "Captain America: The First Avenger":

> The serum amplifies everything that is inside, so good becomes great; bad becomes worse.

The only reason that Emil Blonksy became the Abomination was because he asked for more serum, and eventually pressured Samuel Sterns to give him further treatment.

**Given Blonksy's pre-serum attitude, could the serum he received be considered a success (given that it made him 'worse')? Also if the treatment were used on someone good with the qualities of Steve Rogers could the actual success of Project REBIRTH be replicated?**

Note: This is primarily about the Marvel Cinematic Universe, but if there are comic references that show that other people have the potential that Steve Rogers had under the influence of the super-soldier serum thats good too.

Comment: I seem to recall Blonsky using some form of the super soldier serum, but not the necessary vita-rays, which were essential in the proper successful enhancement. His temperament was likely a factor, but I think the wrong usage of the wrong formula likely had *more* to do with it

Comment: I was sure I saw a screenshot from Incredible Hulk that had "Project: Rebirth" somewhere,but there is a good chance I'm mistaken.

Comment: There is, but lots of versions of the serum were created and tested during Project Rebirth. Erskine died during CA1 and the correct formula and procedure were lost with him. Otherwise, there would be huge armies of super soldiers now.

Comment: Refer to [this question](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/4851/is-the-super-soldier-serum-in-incredible-hulk-the-same-as-the-one-in-captain-ame?rq=1) regarding whether or not it was the same serum given to Steve Rogers.